# concatenating line with previous line

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to concatenate line starting with -abc with its previous line.
It is working fine on terminal but giving error while using on jenkins shell script

sh'''
sed -i -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n-abc/-abc/;ta' -e 'P;D' input.txt
'''

Error : sed: -e expression #2, char 6: unterminated `s' command

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
sed '48s/$/-a/' input
```